# Can I do Math in application+json script?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to perform arithmatic operation in application+json script.
Do you have any idea how can I achieve that?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "my_dynamic_int_variable":"var_1 + var_2"
  }
</script>
```

var_1 and var_2 can be javascript global objects. Need to add two javascript variables in this JSON script.

Comment: No, you can't, if that's actually supposed to be JSON.  JSON property values are simple values, and there are no provisions for computation. You're free to write your own code to interpret the values once the JSON is transformed into a JavaScript object (or anything else).

Comment: Any chance you could attach why you would like it done like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is **No**, you can perform the mathematical equation in JavaScript and then assign the result into your object property.

**Try this :**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var var_1 = 1;
var var_2 = 3;
var obj = {};
obj.my_dynamic_int_variable = var_1 + var_2;
console.log(obj);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```